# nx.is_connected(G) is False, now what?

Tags: graph, networkx

I am using [aves-weaver-social](https://networkrepository.com/aves-weaver-social.php) dataset to understand about graph. I want to calculate the diameter of the graph, but the graph is not connected. I have been trying to get the sub-graphs separately, but I am stuck. I want to process each subgraph one at a time and see its properties.

Thankyou!

Here is the minimal code and image of the graph

```html
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_edgelist('./aves-weaver-social.edges', create_using=nx.Graph, nodetype=int, data=(("weight", int),))
print(nx.is_connected(G))
```

[image]

Comment: please provide the minimal code to load the data and set up the graph, up to the point in which you get `nx.is_connected(G)`

Answer (score 0):

You can split the graph using its [`connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html) and [`subgraph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html):

```
[nx.diameter(G.subgraph(c)) for c in nx.connected_components(G)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 7, 2, 1, 6, 2, 4, 2, 7, 5, 12, 7, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2]
```